# Django weird css issue

Tags: django

I'm facing some weird css issue  with django . My css works fine but some how if i change any rule or add another one it does not take effect .

i'm using this to put css on django :

```
    (r'^/css/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root':'/home/lioy/django_projects/terrasis/css/'}),
```

and it is linked to my base.html :

< link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />

It works . But somehow the changes that i made to my style.css doesnt take effect .I tried to change the background color of one already working propertie and nothing happend. Is that a bug or something .. ?

I restarted the django server and it doesnt make any difference ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To speed up page loads your browser is likely using a cached copy of your CSS file; thinking that it hasn't changed since it was last fetched.

In that case you'll see something like this in the console:

```
[12/Feb/2011 20:50:35] "GET /site_media/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Where the 304 Not Modified status code [means](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> If the client has performed a
>   conditional GET request and access is
>   allowed, but the document has not been
>   modified, the server SHOULD respond
>   with this status code.

You can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force a cache refresh (in Firefox anyway).
After that you should see that the browser fetches the CSS file again, e.g.:

```
[12/Feb/2011 22:05:02] "GET /site_media/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2242
```